# Is it possible to call a method from aura controller to a Lightning Web Controller?

Tags: aura, lightning-web-components

I just started using LWCs

Inside the component that is holding my Lightning Web Component I have a controller with a method:

```js
({
   sObjectName: function(){
        return component.get("v.sObjectName")
   }
})
```

And then I have my LWC. How can I call that function from my LWC? Or even better how can I call `component.get("v.sObjectName") from within the LWC?

Same applies to:

`$A.get("e.force:createRecord")` I want to be able to bring up the create record menu from my LWC.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You should probably complete the LWC Trailhead modules and go through the [introductory documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc).

Comment: [Working with Aura and Lightning Web Components: Interoperability and Migration](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/02/working-with-aura-and-lightning-web-components-interoperability-and-migration.html)

Comment: @glls So it's possible right?

Comment: if your asking how to call aura:methods from within LWC - you cant, if you are trying to trigger a method in an aura component from your LWC, yes.

Comment: FYI you're showing syntax of Aura but you keep saying LWC. I agree with @glls, you need to do the trailheads on Aura Components and Lightning Web Components. They are different programming models and you cannot (directly) call one from the other. Aura call LWC is easier, since you can `@api` expose a LWC method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to invoce an aura method from a LWC - however, you will have to take into consideration that LWC is not supported everywhere as of yet, as mentioned in [Working with Aura and Lightning Web Components: Interoperability and Migration](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/02/working-with-aura-and-lightning-web-components-interoperability-and-migration.html)